# In Wso2 EI 6.2 what is the pagination mechanism for a rest apis and aggregate the response

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying call (Shopify Orders APIs) paginated REST API. And need to aggregate all the responses need one response. But can't find any pagination mediator or any similar way to do that.

I did a work around, I recursively call same sequence and, did the pagination. Problem I have is aggregateor doesn't work as I expected, It did't aggregate paginateed responses in to single response.

Here I have attached the ESB sequence code and the response body of Shopify

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="OrderPaginationSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <log level="custom">
    <property name="hit_text" value="### Shopify All Order Pagination Sequence ###"/>
    <property expression="get-property('pageCount')" name="pageCount"/>
    <property expression="get-property('synapse_it_count')" name="synapseCount"/>
  </log>
  <filter description="" regex="true" source="get-property('synapse_it_count') &lt;= get-property('pageCount') ">
    <then>
      <property expression="get-property('synapse_it_count')+1"
        name="synapse_it_count" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property description="URL Expression"
        expression="fn:concat('/','orders.json?page=',get-property('synapse_it_count'),'&amp;limit=250')"
        name="uri.var.url_expression" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.url_expression')" name="Shopify Order Paggiing Sequence Sequence"/>
      </log>
      <call-template description="" target="SeqTempShopifyApi"/>
      <log level="custom"/>
      <iterate expression="//orders" id="orderPaginationItr" sequential="true">
        <target>
          <sequence>
            <log level="custom">
              <property expression="$body" name="hit_text"/>
            </log>
          </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
      <aggregate id="orderPaginationItr">
        <completeCondition timeout="10">
          <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="//orders">
          <log level="custom">
            <property name="message response" value=""/>
          </log>
        </onComplete>
      </aggregate>
      <sequence key="OrderPaginationSequence"/>
    </then>
    <else/>
  </filter>
</sequence>
```

[Shopify Order API Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#index)

Shopify Order Response

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 450789469,
      "email": "bob.norman@hostmail.com"
    }
  ]
```

}